# How to setup Sceneform SDK 1.16 for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

From what I understand, as of March 2020, the Scenform SDK is now open source, and is available on GitHub. But the [Sceneform documentation](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/android-quickstart) on Google Developers is for the old one.

What is the proper way to set up a Sceneform project in Android Studio in 2020? There always seems to be issues - whether it'd be gradle-related, problems with edit-configuration, etc. Android development is already tricky enough in general. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can easily download `Sceneform 1.16`

For this launch the latest version of Android Studio and go to...:

- **Win** :  File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories
- **Mac** :  Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins

...click `Browse repositories`, and then choose the `Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)`.

## Configure `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files

After this you need to configure your APPS `build.gradle` files the same way you did it for ARCore. Sceneform and ARCore UX dependencies should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.16.0'
    implementation files("../libs/libsceneform_runtime_schemas.jar")
}
```

Also, you have to modify `AndroidManifest.xml` file to indicate that your app uses `AR Optional` or requires `AR Required` ARCore and `CAMERA` access:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" />

<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
</application>
```

Here you can find a [thorough instruction](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/getting-started#import-sceneform-plugin) how you can do it.

Comment: How would this work if I were to download the sample file directly from GitHub (https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk)? Or do you recommend making a blank project and simply inserting the plugins?

Comment: Hi @ErickAdam! Yes, I recommend you install Sceneform plugin via Android Studio. It's the easiest approach.

Comment: Could not find com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.16.0.

Comment: @NoumanCh, here's how it looks on official page. https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformsrc/sceneform/build.gradle . I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I followed the stepd and gettin Error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549520/getsupportfragmentmanager-is-not-accessible I followed whats there in github. am I missing anything

Comment: hi when i right click on andy.obj file and select  import sceneform asset unfortunately this window dont open. i restarted android studio 4.1 and searched whole of sites, but i did not find any solution.

Comment: Hi @hosein, Publish it as a question.