# getSupportFragmentManager() is not accessible

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

## I am creating a basic example and getting this 2 Errors.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Quaternion;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable modelRenderable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

Getting a Error:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment'
```

I have add the import for fragment?

2. Also giving this Error during Build.

   sceneformsrc\sceneform\src\main\java\com\google\ar\sceneform\AnchorNode.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

am missing something that I am getting these errors?

I am using Sceneform 1.16 and Andriod studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/face_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Have you mentioned the android:name tag?

Answer (score 0):

First cross check the fragment name and ensure that the fragment name is `com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If that is correct then add the `SuppressWarnings` annotation for the `onCreate` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable modelRenderable;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    }
}
```